# Caesar cipher in i686 assembly + MMX

Tags: linux, assembly, caesar-cipher, x86

I have written the following implementation of the Caesar cipher for an old Linux computer with a Pentium MMX chip.  The code has been written with the following design goals in mind:

- the code should perform well
- to avoid timing side-channel attacks, the runtime should be independent of the data used
- the code should run on a Pentium MMX

Please let me know of possible improvements and performance pitfalls I fell in.

```
    # MMX caeasar cipher implementation
    # for i586 with MMX
    # signature:
    # caesar(out, in, len, key)
    # key is between 0 and 25

    .section .text
    .globl caesar
    .type caesar,@function
    .align 16
caesar:
    push %ebp
    mov %esp,%ebp
    push %ebx
    push %edi
    push %esi

    mov 8(%ebp),%edi        # edi: destination
    mov 12(%ebp),%esi       # esi: source
    mov 16(%ebp),%edx       # edx: length
    and $~7,%edx            # only process full qwords
    test %edx,%edx
    jz 1f

    xor %ecx,%ecx           # ecx: index
    movd 20(%ebp),%mm5
    punpcklbw %mm5,%mm5
    punpcklwd %mm5,%mm5
    punpckldq %mm5,%mm5     # mm5: key bytes

    movq %mm5,%mm4
    psubb twentysix,%mm4        # mm4: key - 26

    movq Amask,%mm6
    psubb %mm4,%mm6         # mm6: 'A' - 1 - (key - 26)

    .align 16
0:  movq (%esi,%ecx),%mm0
    movq %mm0,%mm1
    pand ucmask,%mm1        # mm1: xmm0 in upper case

    movq %mm1,%mm3
    movq %mm1,%mm2

    pcmpgtb Amask,%mm2      # mm2: 0xff where 'A' <= buf[i]
    pcmpgtb Zmask,%mm3      # mm3: 0xff where 'Z' < buf[i]
    pcmpgtb %mm6,%mm1       # mm1: 0xff where 'A' + key <= buf[i]

    pandn %mm1,%mm3
    pand %mm4,%mm3          # mm3: key-26 where 'A' + (26 - key) <= buf[i] <= 'Z'

    pandn %mm2,%mm1
    pand %mm5,%mm1          # mm1: key where 'A' <= buf[i] < 'A' + (26 - key)

    por %mm3,%mm1           # mm1: 0/key/key-26
    paddb %mm1,%mm0
    movq %mm0,(%edi,%ecx)

    add $8,%ecx
    cmp %edx,%ecx
    jb 0b
    emms
    add %ecx,%edi
    add %ecx,%esi

1:  mov 16(%ebp),%edx       # length
    mov 20(%ebp),%ecx       # key
    and $7,%edx         # loop tail

    # process remaining bytes
    add %edx,%edi       # end of output buffer
    add %edx,%esi       # end of input buffer
    neg %edx        # index counts up to 0

    lea -26(%ecx),%eax  # al: key - 26
    mov $'A'+26-1,%ah
    sub %cl,%ah     # ah: threshold ('A' - 1 - (key - 26))

    .align 16
0:  mov (%esi,%edx),%bl
    and $~0x20,%bl      # bl: uppercase c
    cmp $'Z'+1,%bl      # cf: uc <= 'Z'
    sbb %ch,%ch     # ch: 0xff if uc <= 'Z'
    cmp %bl,%ah     # cf: thresh < uc
    sbb %bh,%bh     # bh: 0xff if thresh < uc
    and %bh,%ch
    and %al,%ch     # ch: key - 26 & isleZ & isgttthres
    not %bh         # bh: ~isgtthresh
    cmp $'A',%bl
    cmc         # cf: 'A' <= uc
    sbb %bl,%bl     # bl: 0xff if 'A' <= uc
    and %bh,%bl
    and %cl,%bl     # bl: key & isgeA & ~isgtthresh
    or %ch,%bl
    add (%esi,%edx),%bl
    mov %bl,(%edi,%edx)
    inc %edx
    jnz 0b

1:  pop %esi
    pop %edi
    pop %ebx
    leave
    ret
    .size caesar,.-caesar

    .section .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
    .type ucmask,@object
ucmask: .fill 8, 1, ~0x20
    .size ucmask, 8
    .type Amask,@object
Amask:  .fill 8, 1, 'A' - 1
    .size Amask, 8
    .type Zmask,@object
Zmask:  .fill 8, 1, 'Z'
    .size Zmask, 8
    .type twentysix,@object
twentysix:
    .fill 8, 1, 26
    .size twentysix, 8
```

You can use this harness to test the code:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern void caesar(const char *out, char *in, size_t len, int key);

extern int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t count;
    int key = 13;

    if (argc > 1)
        key = atoi(argv[1]) % 26;

    while (count = getline(&buf, &len, stdin), count != EOF) {
        caesar(buf, buf, strlen(buf), key);
        fputs(buf, stdout);
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Aren't there 8 mm registers?  Since register<->register operations tend to be faster than register<->memory, could you use mm7 for Amask?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Indeed, that seems useful.

Comment: So you want to tune for P5 (Pentium MMX)?  You mention i686: the first P6 chip with MMX was Pentium II.  (PPro didn't have MMX).  Tuning for out-of-order P6 is significantly different from the in-order dual-issue pipeline in P5.  On P5, most MMX instructions can pair in either the U or V pipes, so instruction scheduling is very important.   On P6, decode bottlenecks and register-read stalls are going to be the major worries, not scheduling.  (And early P6 doesn't have micro-fusion of memory operands; you get 2 uops.)

Comment: Can you require your in/out buffers are padded to a multiple of 8 bytes, so you can use SIMD without a scalar fallback?  (You can already do that by using a possibly-overlapping unaligned last vector, unless the total length is less than 8, though.   If operating in-place with src=dst needs to be supported, make sure you load that last maybe-overlapping source vector before the final main loop vector store.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I am not sure; I think I wrote i686 because I thought this was the first CPU to support MMX.  This whole thing is more of an educational exercise / joke, but optimisation advice for either CPU would still be useful.  Padding cannot be mandated though.

Comment: Too bad; you could make a version with `movd` that worked for sizes from 4 to 7 bytes wide, but not narrower easily.  Anyway yeah, having to work on PMMX means you don't have `pshufw` to save an instruction when broadcasting, and going through an integer reg for `imul $0x01010101, (mem), %eax` is also slow before P6 (slow multiply unit).  But that's outside the loop.  The main thing by far is pairing rules inside the loop, scheduling the code so it will be hard to read.  In the source, indenting comments with different columns can help to keep track of two interleaved chains of operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A big danger.

When the *len* parameter happens to be a muliple of 8 and all of the full qwords have been processed, there will be no remaining bytes to process.
Your code calculates the number of remaining bytes using

```
mov 16(%ebp),%edx     # length
...
and $7,%edx           # loop tail
```

but forgets to exit if this produces zero. The loop that follows is started anyway and at the bottom where it reads

```
inc %edx
jnz 0b
```

the increment of `%edx` will keep producing NZ for a very long time!

Resolve this by exiting if the `and` instruction sets `ZF=1`.

```
mov 16(%ebp), %edx    # length
...
and $7, %edx          # loop tail
jz  1f
```

---

### A small optimization

> ```
> and $~7,%edx        # only process full qwords
> test %edx,%edx
> jz 1f
> ```

Because the `and` instruction defines the zero flag (ZF), there's no need to write `test %edx, %edx`.

---

### Allow me

> ```
> mov $'A'+26-1,%ah
> ```

This struck me as being a bit too much of a complication. Why not simply write

```
mov $'Z', %ah
```

Now if it was your intent to come close to the comment that follows in the next line
`# ah: threshold ('A' - 1 - (key - 26))`
then writing

```
lea -26(%ecx), %eax   # al: key - 26
mov $'A'-1, %ah
sub %al, %ah          # ah: threshold ('A' - 1 - (key - 26))
```

would have nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

After applying the advice I received, this is the final version of the code:

```
    # MMX caeasar chiffre implementation
    # for i686 with MMX
    # signature:
    # caesar(out, in, len, key)
    # key is between 0 and 25

    .section .text
    .globl caesar
    .type caesar,@function
    .align 16
caesar:
    push %ebp
    mov %esp,%ebp
    push %ebx
    push %edi
    push %esi

    mov 8(%ebp),%edi        # edi: destination
    mov 12(%ebp),%esi       # esi: source
    mov 16(%ebp),%edx       # edx: length
    and $~7,%edx            # only process full qwords
    test %edx,%edx
    jz 1f

    xor %ecx,%ecx           # ecx: index
    movd 20(%ebp),%mm5
    punpcklbw %mm5,%mm5
    punpcklwd %mm5,%mm5
    punpckldq %mm5,%mm5     # mm5: key bytes

    movq Amask,%mm7         # for later use

    movq %mm5,%mm4
    psubb twentysix,%mm4        # mm4: key - 26

    movq %mm7,%mm6
    psubb %mm4,%mm6         # mm6: 'A' - 1 - (key - 26)

    .align 16
0:  movq (%esi,%ecx),%mm0
    movq %mm0,%mm1
    pand ucmask,%mm1        # mm1: xmm0 in upper case

    movq %mm1,%mm3
    movq %mm1,%mm2

    pcmpgtb %mm7,%mm2       # mm2: 0xff where 'A' <= buf[i]
    pcmpgtb Zmask,%mm3      # mm3: 0xff where 'Z' < buf[i]
    pcmpgtb %mm6,%mm1       # mm1: 0xff where 'A' + key <= buf[i]

    pandn %mm1,%mm3
    pand %mm4,%mm3          # mm3: key-26 where 'A' + (26 - key) <= buf[i] <= 'Z'

    pandn %mm2,%mm1
    pand %mm5,%mm1          # mm1: key where 'A' <= buf[i] < 'A' + (26 - key)

    por %mm3,%mm1           # mm1: 0/key/key-26
    paddb %mm1,%mm0
    movq %mm0,(%edi,%ecx)

    add $8,%ecx
    cmp %edx,%ecx
    jb 0b
    emms
    add %ecx,%edi
    add %ecx,%esi

1:  mov 16(%ebp),%edx       # length
    mov 20(%ebp),%ecx       # key
    and $7,%edx         # loop tail
    jz 1f               # all bytes processed alread?

    # process remaining bytes
    add %edx,%edi           # end of output buffer
    add %edx,%esi           # end of input buffer
    neg %edx            # index counts up to 0

    lea -26(%ecx),%ebx      # bl: key - 26
    mov $'A'-1,%ah
    sub %bl,%ah         # ah: threshold ('A' - 1 - (key - 26))

    .align 16
0:  mov (%esi,%edx),%al
    and $~0x20,%al          # al: uppercase c
    cmp $'Z'+1,%al          # cf: uc <= 'Z'
    sbb %ch,%ch         # ch: 0xff if uc <= 'Z'
    cmp %al,%ah         # cf: thresh < uc
    sbb %bh,%bh         # bh: 0xff if thresh < uc
    and %bh,%ch
    and %al,%ch         # ch: key - 26 & isleZ & isgttthres
    not %bh             # bh: ~isgtthresh
    cmp $'A',%al
    cmc             # cf: 'A' <= uc
    sbb %al,%al         # al: 0xff if 'A' <= uc
    and %bh,%al
    and %cl,%al         # al: key & isgeA & ~isgtthresh
    or %ch,%al
    add (%esi,%edx),%al
    mov %al,(%edi,%edx)
    inc %edx
    jnz 0b

1:  pop %esi
    pop %edi
    pop %ebx
    leave
    ret
    .size caesar,.-caesar

    .section .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
    .type ucmask,@object
ucmask: .fill 8, 1, ~0x20
    .size ucmask, 8
    .type Amask,@object
Amask:  .fill 8, 1, 'A' - 1
    .size Amask, 8
    .type Zmask,@object
Zmask:  .fill 8, 1, 'Z'
    .size Zmask, 8
    .type twentysix,@object
twentysix:
    .fill 8, 1, 26
    .size twentysix, 8
```